# Create multiple tokens and manage multiple wallets from the platform

Tags: tokens, wallets, private-blockchain, markets

I'm new to blockchain and Ethereum, I currently started researching about to work on a new project.

I wanted to ask for advice on what should I use or what it will fits better for my use case:

In my case, on the platform can join multiple users, and those can create projects. The idea is to create a Token for each project and then let all the users use a private stock market to trade all those tokens.

So, when a user creates a project, the platform should automatically create the tokens for that. Also, each user should have their wallet integrated on the platform. With that, they must use our interface to use their wallet and trade on our private stock market. (So we can control that those wallets are only used to manage the tokens created on our platform and through our platform simplifying the process for the user).

Private Stock Market? Yes, I would like to create something that firstly I don't know if it's possible, but I would like our tokens only being tradable through our platform in order to evade the externalization of those to other markets.

**What I think it should fit:**
I've been looking for few blockchains that could accomplish our requirements, and I think the following two could be the best for it:
[BigChainDB](https://www.bigchaindb.com), that seems easy to work with and to be able to manage the stock market. 
[Ethereum](https://www.ethereum.org/), obviously this was the first blockchain that I thought about because of the possibility to create tokens and smart contracts, but what I don't know and find any explanation about, is to moderate multiple wallets from the same place (in this case, the platform).

**Problems:**
For Ethereum, I have not found anything about the management of the multiple wallets; I don't know if it's possible to limit the commercialization of the created tokens through our private stock market, and also, as far as I understand, the process of creation of something like this could be very expensive and extensive.

Then appears BigChainDB that seems to fit well for this project and the process and costs of creating it should be much less than with ethereum, but then I wanted to look for external information about them and I didn't found anything. On BitcoinTalk nobody is taking about it, and the same for the other big forums I found about Crypto and Blockchain. Their [github](https://github.com/bigchaindb/bigchaindb) have updates from one month ago and 3k+ stars and 600+ forks, so it should be active. Also their [Gitter](https://gitter.im/bigchaindb/bigchaindb) seems active this month and the past ones, but it's weird that I couldn't find opinions nor related posts from this last year about it.

Could some one give me advice about my situation?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea itself of a token doesn't require a smart-contract, you could implement it yourself with a centralized database, it's just an entry in the database like it's an "entry" in the contract.

You have to ask yourself : **Do I need smart-contracts for what I do?**

If it's in the idea of a dapp where users have full control of what they own and can transfer as they will their tokens even if the website is down, then **yes**.

Now, if you don't care about this aspect, it will probably be cheaper for you in terms of speed and money to choose either a centralized database or to pick [Amazon's own ledger](https://aws.amazon.com/en/qldb/) which has a central authority. It's relatively cheap and seems to be fast. (I do not work for Amazon ;) .)

If you absolutely want to use smart-contracts on Ethereum, it's always possible to craft a solution fitting your needs, just need a bit of creativity. As for BigChainDB, I have never used it or looked into it, so I can't say.

You can always do a mix of both : centralized database for the tokens and such, and a public ledger for registering the transfers of tokens.

Comment: I didn't know about Amazon QLDB and seems to fit perfect for the project, and the price is so much better than developing all the smart contracts and implement the blockchain to the project.
I was thinking about something like use DB as normal to store tokens and transactions and then generate a hash and store it on a blockchain, but that really doesn't fit with what I wanted, but seems that QLDB solves this effectively. 
With Amazon QLDB I can give enough confidence to the users about the security on the transactions and how the tokens are managed.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In Ethereum you may design token smart contract in such a way that it will allow token transfers to whitelisted addresses only.  You may implement white list either in token contract itself, or in separate contract shared among several token contracts.  In later case, token contracts will ask whitelist contract for whether particular address is whitelisted or not.  Let me know if you need more details, I will add them to the answer.